# TimeSeriesForecast for a range

Tags: time-series

Now I have a `tsm`, say `tsm=TimeSeriesModelFit[data]`.
Now, while using `TimeSeriesForecast` to forecast it, is there a way to let *Mathematica* only print the result in my desired range, say larger than 10 but smaller than 20.

Answer (score 6):

Using some `data` from the [documentation of `TimeSeriesModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesModelFit.html)

```
data = {5., 9., 8., 10., 6.1, 10.4, 9.1, 11.6, 7.5, 12.1, 10.4, 13.5, 9., 14.1, 11.9, 15.7, 
  10.8, 16.4, 13.7, 18.3, 12.9, 19., 15.8, 21.2, 15.3, 22.1, 18.3, 24.6};

tsm = TimeSeriesModelFit[data];

tsf = TimeSeriesForecast[tsm, {10, 20}];

ListLinePlot[{TimeSeries[data], tsf}]
```

[image: Plot1]

```
tsf["Path"]
```

> ```
> {{37, 36.7126}, {38, 31.2892}, {39, 41.3135}, {40, 33.7416}, {41, 44.8659}, 
>  {42, 39.0431}, {43, 50.7289}, {44, 42.9233}, {45, 55.6801}, {46, 49.5727}, {47, 63.1753}}
> ```

---

Or

```
forecast = {#, tsm[#]} & /@ Range[37, 47]
```

> ```
> {{37, 36.7126}, {38, 31.2892}, {39, 41.3135}, {40, 33.7416}, {41, 44.8659}, 
>  {42, 39.0431}, {43, 50.7289}, {44, 42.9233}, {45, 55.6801}, {46, 49.5727}, {47, 63.1753}}
> ```

```
ListLinePlot[{TimeSeries[data], forecast}]
```

[image: Plot2]

Comment: sorry my question is that, the mathematica will only output the result in my desired range... not the number of steps forward...

Comment: @YinchengLiu Edited.